# Selecting a range of cells throws run-time error '1004'

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a VBA problem which finds lines which are considered to be invalid, saves the row number in an array called `invalidRowsToDelete` and deletes the selected rows by building a string of the invalid rows (e.g. `1:1, 4:4, 7:7`).

However, it sometimes works, it sometimes doesn't, but fails more consistently with large amounts of invalid rows.

The error it returns is: **"Runtime error '1004': Method range of object '_global' failed"**  on the line `Set rng = Range(invalidRowsToDelete)`

```
Public rng As Range
__________________________


Dim invalidRowsToDelete As String
Dim i As Long

For i = LBound(InvalidFilesArr) To UBound(InvalidFilesArr)

    If InvalidFilesArr(i) <> "" Then
        invalidRowsToDelete = invalidRowsToDelete & InvalidFilesArr(i) & ":" & InvalidFilesArr(i) &     ","
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

'Build range statement and delete trailing comma from rowsToDeleteStatement
invalidRowsToDelete = "" & Left(invalidRowsToDelete, Len(invalidRowsToDelete) - 1) & ""
Debug.Print invalidRowsToDelete

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Set rng = Range(invalidRowsToDelete) #### Problem line

rng.Select
rng.Delete
```

This has had me for quite a while now and I can't work out the reason for it causing this error.

Thanks

Comment: My guess, although I can't find anything to support it, is that your string gets too long and overflows the `range` method.

Comment: The limit seems to be 255.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a string to build a complicated range reference is generally a bad idea.  I would use the loop to build the range instead of the string that describes the range.

```
Public rng As Range
__________________________


Dim invalidRowsToDelete As String
Dim i As Long

i = LBound(InvalidFilesArr)
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(InvalidFilesArr(i))

For i = LBound(InvalidFilesArr) + 1 To UBound(InvalidFilesArr)
    If InvalidFilesArr(i) = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
    Set rng = Union(rng, Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(InvalidFilesArr(i)))
Next i

rng.Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just delete the rows there and then when you find them?

```
Public rng As Range

Dim invalidRowsToDelete As String
Dim i As Long

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
For i = LBound(InvalidFilesArr) To UBound(InvalidFilesArr)
    If InvalidFilesArr(i) <> "" Then
        Set rng = Range(InvalidFilesArr(i) & ":" & InvalidFilesArr(i))
        rng.Select
        rng.Delete
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: You need to be careful doing it like this.  After deleting row 5, What was row 10 is now row 9.  As written you will delete the wrong rows.

Comment: This would work just fine if you change `For i = LBound(InvalidFilesArr) To UBound(InvalidFilesArr)` to `For i = UBound(InvalidFilesArr) To LBound(InvalidFilesArr) Step -1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is *"bad";*  to find out why replace:

```
Set rng = Range(invalidRowsToDelete)
```

with:

```
On Error GoTo GhostBusters
Set Rng = Range(invalidRowsToDelete)
```

and at the bottom of the sub include:

```
GhostBusters:
MsgBox Len(invalidRowsToDelete)
MsgBox invalidRowsToDelete
On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Union` to get the range to be deleted and then call `Delete` on this range. HTH

```
Dim rngToDelete As Range
Dim rngRow As Range
Dim rowsToDelete(0 To 5) As Long
Dim i As Long

rowsToDelete(0) = 2
rowsToDelete(1) = 5
rowsToDelete(2) = 7
rowsToDelete(3) = 9
rowsToDelete(4) = 10
rowsToDelete(5) = 12

For i = LBound(rowsToDelete) To UBound(rowsToDelete)
    Set rngRow = ActiveSheet.Rows(rowsToDelete(i))
    If rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
        Set rngToDelete = rngRow
    Else
        Set rngToDelete = Application.Union(rngToDelete, rngRow)
    End If
Next i

if Not rngToDelete Is Nothing Then rngToDelete.Delete
```